# Custom UIImagePickerController

Tags: ios, swift, uiimagepickercontroller

I would like to create a custom UIImagePickerController just like the Facebook or Pinterest one. The custom view should show list of images as grid with the first cell is a small camera view or button to present camera.

Is there any swift open source that helps me make it faster or I have to do it from scratch?

Comment: use Photos Framework, you would find it is not that difficult to fetch Photos,  add some UI code then

Comment: Is there any code snipet or example please?

Answer (score 2):

I have an open source `PHImageManager` based photo browser/picker. You can find it in [my GitHub repository here](https://github.com/FlexMonkey/PhotoBrowserDemo). It even implements 3D Touch for peeking at images :)

Hope it helps,

Simon

Answer (score 0):

You should use this: [AssetsLibrary](http://AssetsLibrary) to get photo from devices

Then you can use UICollectionView to show photos with the first Item is an camera icon. When user select that cell show the camera.

Or you could use this: [AQGridView](https://github.com/AlanQuatermain/AQGridView) to implement into your project.

Good luck!